# How to really permanently delete shared files on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I have just deleted a great number of folders and files in my Google Drive, some of which were shared with any unknown persons, I haven't checked and can't remember. Deleting worked fine at first, the folders and files disappeared from my Drive. I then emptied the recycle bin. But the used space didn't decrease.

The list of the largest files still contains many (or all) of the shared files I just "deleted". They shall be located in the recycle bin and I was offered to restore them. Which I don't want to do.

What can I do to really delete those files from everywhere and forever, no matter whether some of them were shared with other users or the public? Those files are not needed anymore and I want to clean things up and not leave any data somewhere unnecessary.

Comment: It will take up to a month before they are truly deleted. This is to ensure you can restore files upon accidentally deleting them. They should not count for your total drive usage in the sense that you should be able to store files to the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it turned out Google is just a bit slow with deleting stuff. Now, four hours later, the files seem to be gone and the free space is back.